# In Perl, can I use constants to facilitate compile time detection of typos in method invocations?

Tags: perl

I have the following program in Perl:

```
use Class::Struct;

use constant {
    ACTION => "Action",
    TYPE => "Type"
};

struct MyClass => {           
    &ACTION => '$',
    &TYPE => '$'
};

my $obj = new MyObj{
    &ACTION => 'add',
    &TYPE => '1'
}

# compilation error:
var $action = $obj->&ACTION;
```

I get a compilation error when trying to access the object field using a constant. Is it possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it is no good practice to store you method names in constants

Comment: What exactly are you actually attempting to accomplish here?

Comment: PS, `&ACTION` turns your constant into a run-time sub call. You want `+ACTION`!

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, Compile-time detection of typos, I think. You can only omit the parameter list for previously declared subs. Of course, by adding `&`, the OP is defying that purpose.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, that makes sense. But I think `$x->+ACTION` is still a syntax error.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, Correct. It's not a solution to the problem the OP asked about.

Comment: Thanks guys, the reason I wanted to use constants is that I need to use the same names in other places. This is only a sample of my entire code. So instead of writing the explicit names I wanted to use Constants which will be less pain if I'll decide to make changes in the names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code includes some errors such as trying to instantiate `MyObj` when all you declared was `MyClass` and using `var` instead of `my`. With those fixed, you'll note that `->&` is a syntax error. See [Method Invocation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Invocation) and [Method Call Variations](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Call-Variations).

You can use

- Method Names as Strings
- Subroutine References as Methods
- Deferencing Method Call

That said, here is your code with the corrections to enable it to compile and run:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Class::Struct;

use constant {
    ACTION => "Action",
    TYPE => "Type"
};

struct MyClass => {
    ACTION() => '$',
    TYPE() => '$'
};

my $obj = MyClass->new(
    ACTION() => 'add',
    TYPE() => '1'
);

print $obj->${ \ACTION };
```

Note that using `ACTION()` rather than `&ACTION` in the declarations will turn the keys to compile time constants rather than runtime subroutine invocations (prefixing `ACTION` with `&` tells `perl` to ignore the empty prototype, effectively undoing the benefit of `use constant`).

It uses the [Dereferencing Method Call](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Call-Variations):

> #### Deferencing Method Call
>
> Perl also lets you use a dereferenced scalar reference in a method call. That's a mouthful, so let's look at some code:
>
> ```
>   $file->${ \'save' };
>   $file->${ returns_scalar_ref() };
>   $file->${ \( returns_scalar() ) };
>   $file->${ returns_ref_to_sub_ref() };
> ```

The code above compiles to `$obj->${ \'Action' }`.

As usual, @ikegami spotted something I missed: `$x->doesnotexist` is a run-time error. By using constants as method names, it would be possible to detect typos at compile time. For example, if I had made a mistake such as `$obj->${ \ACITON };`, the compilation would have failed.

In that case, [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast) might provide an aesthetically more pleasing solution (even though it would come at a speed penalty relative to using constant subroutines):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Class::Struct;
use Const::Fast;

const my $ACTION => 'Action';
const my $TYPE => 'Type';

struct MyClass => {
    $ACTION => '$',
    $TYPE => '$'
};

my $obj = MyClass->new(
    $ACTION => 'add',
    $TYPE => '1'
);

print $obj->$ACION;
```

Output:

```
C:\...\Temp> perl -c tt.pl
Global symbol "$ACION" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $ACION"?) at tt.pl line 21.
tt.pl had compilation errors.
```

That is, such a typo would also be detected at compile time. There is a performance penalty for this over using constant subroutines, but it is less ugly.

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate your professional answer. It helps a lot.